How to calculate the basis tensors for a (2,2) tensor
Let
$$\mathbf{e}_{1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\mathbf{e}_{2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{e}_1 \otimes \mathbf{e}_1 &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
e_{11} e_{11} & e_{11} e_{12} \\
e_{12} e_{11} & e_{12} e_{12} 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{e}_1 \otimes \mathbf{e}_2 &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
e_{11} e_{21} & e_{11} e_{22} \\
e_{12} e_{21} & e_{12} e_{22} 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0& 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{e}_2 \otimes \mathbf{e}_1 &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
e_{21} e_{11} & e_{21} e_{12} \\
e_{22} e_{11} & e_{22} e_{12} 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{e}_2 \otimes \mathbf{e}_2 &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
e_{21} e_{21} & e_{21} e_{22} \\
e_{22} e_{21} & e_{22} e_{22} 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Let
$$e^{1} (\mathbf{v}) = v_{1} \quad e^{2}(\mathbf{v}) = v_2$$
Then
\begin{align*}
(e^{1} \otimes e^1)(\cdot, \cdot) & = e^{1}(\cdot) e^{1} (\cdot) \\
(e^{1} \otimes e^2)(\cdot, \cdot) & = e^{1}(\cdot) e^{2} (\cdot) \\
(e^{2} \otimes e^1)(\cdot, \cdot) & = e^{2}(\cdot) e^{1} (\cdot) \\
(e^{2} \otimes e^2)(\cdot, \cdot) & = e^{2}(\cdot) e^{2} (\cdot) \\
\end{align*}
So then by this logic
$$\mathbf{e}_1 \otimes \mathbf{e}_2 \otimes e^{1} \otimes e^{2} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0& 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\otimes 
\left( e^{1}(\cdot) e^{2} (\cdot) 
\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0& e^{1}(\cdot) e^{2} (\cdot) \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
What's wrong with this logic? Can you explain the proper way to compute $e_1 \otimes e_2 \otimes e^1 \otimes e^2$?

What should be wrong with it? It is still correct, if you remember that the table does not stand for a linear operator, but a tensor product. (Of course $V\otimes V$ can be seen as $Hom(V,V^*)$, so there is an interpretation as linear operator,...)


Those $2\times 2$-matrices are nice to visualize, say, $\mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_j$ but cannot be used for what you are trying to do.

To begin with, there are six different types of $(2,2)$-tensors
and you should first decide which type you want the basis for. The first tensor type is the one that eats covectors in the first two slots
and vectors in the last two slots. Its basis is


$$
\mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_j \otimes \mathbf{e}^k \otimes\mathbf{e}^\ell 
$$
where $i,j,k,\ell$ run through $\{1,2\}\,.$

Another type eats a covector in the first and third slot
and a vector in the second and fourth slot. This space  this built from the basis
$$
\mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}^j \otimes \mathbf{e}_k \otimes \mathbf{e}^\ell\,,\quad i,j,k,\ell\in\{1,2\}\,.
$$

Can you finish?



That was super helpful. Thank you! :)
